# Updating a Bit Field with Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

am getting this error once i try to update a bit field with null.  please note that technically the bit is set to 'allow null'.

am getting this error : 
'Object of type 'System.DBNull' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable`

When I do this :

```
 e.NewValues.Add("IdleBlock", DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an actual `null` instead of `DBNull.Value`. As you can see in the error message it's trying to convert the latter into a `null`, so I'm guessing EF wants a proper null value and handle conversion on it's own.

**Edit**: Err, actually I think I'm wrong here. It wants a `System.Nullable` not a null. Try passing it a new System.Nullable with `Value` set to `null`?

Comment: i tried that before trying the DBNULL.Value, for some odd reason it is taking the null as false O.o

Comment: Updated my answer but I'm sort of shooting in the dark here. No VS available to me at the moment so can't try it myself.

Comment: ok i tried this :
                System.Nullable<bool> test = null;
                e.NewValues.Add("IdleBlock", test );

Comment: didn't work tho, it is still setting it to false... thanks for trying to help ^_^